# How to prove $\sum_{f=1}^{n} 2^{f- 1} = 2^n-1$ without expanding?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, contest-math

Without expanding prove that $$\sum_{f=1}^{n}2^{f-1}=2^n-1$$

Comment: Induction is the basic approach.

Comment: (By the way, what do you mean by "expanding" here?)

Comment: Can you use the geometric progression formula?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews expanding means 1+2+4+…

Comment: Can I know why I received downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction proof.

For $n=1$, $$\sum_{f=1}^{1} 2^{f-1} = 2^0 = 1 = 2^{1}-1.$$
Assume true for $n$. Then:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{f=1}^{n+1} 2^{f-1} &=\left(\sum_{f=1}^{n} 2^{f-1}\right) + 2^n \\
&=2^n-1 + 2^n\\
&= 2^n(1+1)-1\\
&=2^{n+1}-1
\end{align}$$

So by induction on $n$, it is true for all natural numbers $n\geq 1$.

---

Induction is the heart of $\Sigma$ notation, at least for finite sums. $\Sigma$ is defined inductively, and almost all proofs that "expand" the sum are actually doing intuitive induction.

Answer (score 3):

You can write it
as a telescoping series
using
$2^{f-1}
=2^{f}-2^{f-1}
$.

Everything cancels except
$2^{n}-1$.

Comment: I didn't understand "everything cancels except $2^n-1$"?

Comment: While the method is nice, somehow the telescoping property requires to "expand the sum" (if I understood OP correctly).

Comment: @Surb Telescoping sums can, of course, be proved inductively, without "expanding." There is no way to avoid induction when doing $\Sigma$ proofs, since the $\Sigma$ is actually defined inductively.

Answer (score 1):

The given sum is 
$$\sum_{f=1}^n2^{f-1}=$$
This is a geometric series
SO
its summation is given by this formula:
$$\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$
Here $a=1$ and $r=2$
$$\frac{1-2^n}{1-2}=2^n-1$$

Comment: Disregards the "without expanding" constraint, but still works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a geometric progression and we have that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}r^k=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Let :}~~~f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^{i-1}$$

$$\begin{align}2f(n)&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^{i}\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}2^{i-1}\\
&=2^n+\Bigg(\sum_{i=2}^{n}2^{i-1}+1\Bigg)-1\\
&=2^n+\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^{i-1}-1\\
&=2^n-1+f(n)\end{align}$$

So:
$$\begin{align}2f(n)-f(n)&=2^n-1\\f(n)&=2^n-1\end{align}$$

Comment: I didn't get third step .

Comment: @Noddy suppose if the sum would have been from $i=1$ then the extra term would have been 1 ($2^{1-1}$), so I added and subtracted to make the sum complete from $i=1$ to $n$.